# Usage of myriad as a noun

Tags: nouns, word-usage

Can the word *myriad* be used in a stand-alone fashion, without a subsequent *of* prepositional?

*He rose to address the myriad, and wept.*

The word is a noun, and this usage sounds poetic to me, and I can't think of any reason beyond convention why it must precede an *of* (especially if there is sufficient context establishing the items being vaguely quantified)

Perhaps switching the article makes it more awkward:

*He rose to address a myriad, and wept.*

However, qualifying it suddenly brings it around:

*He rose to address an assembling myriad, and wept.*

Comment: Related, and possibly, duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/20133/14666

Answer (score 2):

Nothing special about *myriad* as such.

> He rose to address **the poor** and **the sick**.

The definite article can 'nounify' an adjective!

> *He rose to address **a** myriad, and wept.

---

Incidentally, the noun and the adjective forms of *myriad* have different meanings and usage.

Comment: Ah nice.. i hadn't considered examples like "the poor", etc..  I've just been on the receiving end of a lecture that myriad must be followed by "of", when used as a quantifying noun, so this definitely helps

Comment: @user59038 I read *the myriad* here as a poetic substitute for *the masses*, like *the multitude*, but Kris' point is valid. Consider for example *[the six hundred](http://library.sc.edu/spcoll/britlit/tenn/charge.html)*, *[the five thousand](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+14%3A13-21&version=RSVCE)*, or *[the million](http://books.google.com/books/about/Educating_the_Million.html?id=jHL5cQAACAAJ)*.

Answer (score 1):

*Myriad* was a noun before it was an adjective, and its earliest meaning was ‘ten thousand’. It later came to mean, when used in the singular, ‘a countless number of specified things’. There would thus seem to be no grammatical reason why it cannot be used in the way shown in your examples. Whether or not it is a wise stylistic choice is another matter.

Comment: POS apart, (after all, *myriad* is still a noun in contemporary English), why the need for the definite article here then? Why is the indefinite article awkward? "He rose to address a ten thousand," should be fine, as "He addressed a million". I had tried that route but could not see light.

Comment: @Kris: *A ten thousand* sounds as awkward  as *a one man*, as addressed in various questions. *A million* is certainly fine; *a myriad* is equally so, though the question remains whether it means 'a unit of ten thousand' or 'a large number'